# Thunderbird 114/115 reshuffled the interface again, how to fix it

Tags: email, thunderbird, user-interface

Thunderbird is going through yet another main window UI reshuffling in version 114. They call this change [supernova](https://www.askvg.com/thunderbird-to-get-multi-line-message-list-view-in-version-114/)

[image]

(this is TB 114.0b6 ; TB 115 release is next month.)

My question: How can I get Thunderbird back to how it was: Menu bar at the top, then a toolbar, possibly with the "search" box, hamburger menu etc? i.e. the way it was like before this change?

Comment: Versions 114/115 aren't well-known at the moment. You could disable TB updates until the time that a way is found to return to the classical view.

Comment: Bookmarking because I just got auto-updated to v115 and the new UI is _awful_.  

For now I installed v102, disabled automatic updates, and added `-allow-downgrade` on my Thunderbird shortcut.  

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/102.15.1/win64/en-US/

Comment: I was able to fully disable updates on Windows via RegEdit: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1314978

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the copy of 115.1.0 that was recently pushed to me...

1. Make sure Edit > View > Layout > Classic is selected
2. If necessary, go into Edit > Settings and toggle Window Layout > Hide system window titlebar.
3. Right-click inside the toolbar and toggle "Menu Bar" if it's not visible.
4. Follow [these instructions](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/wiki/index/tutorials/#wiki_setup) to enable `userChrome.css` support in Thunderbird. (Basically you need to set the`toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` preference to true, but they also have useful advice on things like live-editing `userChrome.css` in Thunderbird.)
5. To put the menu bar back above the toolbar, add

   ```
   #toolbar-menubar { order: -1 !important; }
   ```

   to your `chrome/userChrome.css` within your profile folder.
6. To get rid of the pills around the message counts, add something like this to your `chrome/userChrome.css`:

   ```
   .folder-count-badge {
     color: black !important;
     background: none !important;
   }
   ```

   I chose to tweak them instead:

   ```
   /* Make the unread messages badges less visually overwhelming
     (Because I use Unread Folders view) */
   :root {
     --folderpane-unread-count-text: #222 !important;
     --folderpane-unread-count-background: #eee !important;
     --folderpane-unread-new-count-background: #6da3d9 !important;
   }
   .new-messages .folder-count-badge {
     color: white !important;
     background-color: var(--folderpane-unread-new-count-background) !important;
   }
   #folderTree:focus-within li.selected > .container .folder-count-badge {
     color: white !important;
   }
   ```
7. Use "Customize..." in the toolbar context menu to remove the flexible spacer to the left of the toolbar buttons to un-center them. (Note the tab bar at the top of that customize window. You'll need to do it separately for each of the global toolbar's contexts.)
8. Use "Hide Folder Pane Header" in the hamburger menu on the folder pane header.
9. Uncheck View > Layout > Message List Header

I did some other things, but I think they were to restore customizations I made which you may have not (eg. setting the message view toolbar back to icons only using "Customize..." in its overflow menu)

I'm still trying to figure out:

1. How to fix the global defaults for column widths in the message list pane so From and Date aren't so huge and Subject isn't so small. (The closest I've found is manually selecting "Context Menu > Apply current view to... > Folder and its children..." for each account individually.)
2. How to get the Quick Filter toolbar to show text labels for the filter buttons again. (It has no context menu or overflow menu where a "Customize..." would go.)
3. How to get the Folder List pane back to being sorted "Inbox, All Mail, Mail Folders, RSS Folders".

Comment: I didn't experience my buttons being centered, but maybe that's because of previous fiddling. The userChrome hack is what I was missing. I can answer your question (3.), but please post it as another question and ping me, since it's not really part of the answer to my original question...

Comment: I'll try to do that later today or tomorrow, but, having fiddled with it a bit more, I realize that I need to clarify that I don't just want any old "grouped view", but, specifically, the grouped sorting I used to have on the non-hierarchical "Unread Folders, Compact View" layout. (i.e. The linear list of folders containing folders with unread messages and nothing else, with all the inboxes at the top of the list and so on, but *not* "unified folders".)

Comment: @einpoklum Done → https://superuser.com/questions/1804878/restoring-folder-type-and-then-alphabetical-sorting-for-folder-pane-in-thunder

Comment: Do you have any glue how to move control buttons like maximize/close to menu panel (instead of toolbar)?

Comment: @Maxim That should be asked as a new question but me personally? No. I just unchecked "Hide system window titlebar" so I have no reason to explore playing around with non-system-drawn maximize/close buttons.

Comment: I will try that idea... good point.

Comment: My hero, thanks a lot.

Comment: thank you kindly