# Restoring "Folder Type and then Alphabetical" Sorting For Folder Pane in Thunderbird 115

Tags: thunderbird

Prior to the Thunderbird UI refresh, the primary sorting key for the contents of the folders pane would be the folders' types (with alphabetical sorting of the folder names being the secondary sorting key) when configured to display as a linear/non-hierarchical list by selecting "Unread Folders" and deselecting "Unified Folders".

That is, all the inboxes would be at the top, all the RSS folders would be at the bottom, and various other types of folders would be in the middle.

(In essence, indirectly sorting by "how urgently/mandatorily you need to look at this".)

Is there a way to restore this useful behaviour in Thunderbird 115 without resorting to downgrading or seeking out an alternative mail client? If so, how?

[image]

Comment: Ah, so, I misunderstood the question when you asked it in the comment. I'm sorry! I don't have an answer to the question as you meant it (as I don't use this display mode)...